# Stripe RailsJS, Cannot charge a customer that has no active card

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, devise, stripe-payments

I keep getting the "Cannot charge a user that has no active card" error when trying to bill a test user.

The app works so that a user gets charged $10 on sign up after they input their CC credentials.

I know the customers are being created but the charges aren't being sent

[image]

Here is the Stripe error

[image]

My credit_card_form.js file which is what collects the credit card info and sends it to stripe without it hitting my database.

```html
$(document).ready(function(){
 var show_error, stripeResponseHandler, submitHandler;
 
 submitHandler = function (event) {
  var $form = $(event.target);
  $form.find("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
  //If Stripe was initialized correctly this will create a token using the credit card info
  if(Stripe){
   Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);
   show_error("CC token generated") 
  } else {
   show_error("Failed to load credit card processing functionality. Please reload this page in your browser.")
  }

  return false;

  };
 // calling the SUBMIT
 $(".cc_form").on('submit', submitHandler);
 
 // RESPONSE HANDLER
 stripeResponseHandler = function (status, response) {
   var token, $form;
   $form = $('.cc_form');
   if (response.error) {
    console.log(response.error.message);
    show_error(response.error.message);
    $form.find("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
   } else {
    token = response.id;
    $form.append($("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"payment[token]\" />").val(token));
    $("[data-stripe=number]").remove();
    $("[data-stripe=cvv]").remove();
    $("[data-stripe=exp-year]").remove();
    $("[data-stripe=exp-month]").remove();
    $("[data-stripe=label]").remove();
    $form.get(0).submit();
   }

   return false;

 };
 
 //ERROR HANDLING
 show_error = function (message) {
  if($("#flash-messages").size() < 1){
   $('div.container.main div:first').prepend("<div id='flash-messages'></div>")
   }
   $("#flash-messages").html('<div class="alert alert-warning"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><div id="flash_alert">' + message + '</div></div>');
   $('.alert').delay(5000).fadeOut(3000);
   
  return false;
 };

});
```

And payment.rb

```html
class Payment < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :card_number, :card_cvv, :card_expires_month, :card_expires_year
  belongs_to :user
  
  def self.month_options
    Date::MONTHNAMES.compact.each_with_index.map{|name,i| ["#{i+1} - #{name}", i+1]}
  end
  
  def self.year_options
    (Date.today.year..(Date.today.year+10)).to_a
  end
  
  def process_payment
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create email:email, card:token

    
    Stripe::Charge.create customer:customer.id, amount: 1000, description: "Premium", currency: "usd"
  end
  
end
```

And a snippet of the devise registrations new.html.erb which is where the user will be charged from

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <%=p .select :card_expires_month, options_for_select(Payment.month_options), {include_blank: "Month"}, "data-stripe"=>"exp-month", class: "form-control", required: true%>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <%=p .select :card_expires_year, options_for_select(Payment.year_options.push), {include_blank: "Year"}, class: "form-control", data: {stripe: "exp-year"}, required: true%>
</div>
```

I know that the customers are being created but I have no clue why my customers aren't paying when I use the test credit card numbers. No answers on stack overflow have helped me as of yet.

Comment: Do the customers that are being created in Stripe have credit cards attached to them?

Comment: the credit card is attached on sign up as you can see from the last code snippet. But javascript dumps the credit card before it gets saved to the user so it doesn't hit the db

Comment: What I mean is, if you go into the Stripe Dashboard and navigate to one of the customers in there, do you see a credit card in there?

Comment: Sorry, and no I do not

Comment: Cool. And how about all of the debugging info that your JS is generating —  can you determine how far it's getting before something is going wrong? Also, is the `card_token` present in the `params` of the request going to your server?

Comment: It *may* be because you're adding the card to the stripe customer with the key `card`, where it should be `source`. https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#create_customer

Comment: Where are you getting `card_token` from I state in `def process_payment` that it is equal to `... , card: token` and no credit card hits my DB all I am seeing in the terminal is my SendGrid information when I register a new user with a test credit card

Comment: changed card:token to source:token and it is still showing the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127341/discussion-between-doctororange-and-jack).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jack and I [had a chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127341/discussion-between-doctororange-and-jack) and discovered that Stripe.js wasn't loading, so the token wasn't being sent in the request.

The issue was `<%= javascript_include_tag 'https://js/stripe.com/v2' %>` being a mistyped js link in `application.html.erb`

The fix was making it `<%= javascript_include_tag 'https://js.stripe.com/v2/' %>`